# Why is this code printing '7'

Tags: heap-memory, stack-memory

Why is this code printing '7'
Trying to understand how the Stack and Heap looks like and how does it looks in the memory allocation

```
public static void Main()
{
    Cls a = new Cls();
    a.v = 3;
    Func(a);
    Console.WriteLine(a.v);
}

class Cls
{
    public int v;
}

static void Func(Cls a)
{
    a.v = 7;
    a = new Cls();
    a.v = 2;
}
```

If you can attach a scatch of stack and heap with memory it will really appreciated

Comment: Because you are setting `a.v = 7`. The next assignment `a.v = 2` is on a totally separate `Cls`, not related in any way to the first one.

Comment: What you are probably confused about, is that variables and objects are two separate concepts. By doing `a = new Cls()`, you don't overwrite the original object `a` was pointing to. You redirect `a` to point to another object.

Comment: Please tag with the used language (Java?)

Answer (score 1):

```
static void Func(Cls a)
{
    a.v = 7;   <----- This is modifying the Cls you create in Main function
    a = new Cls();
    a.v = 2;   <----- This is a new and locally referenced Cls whose value is neither returned to the main function nor is a global variable
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a pointer to the first **Cls** instance. The second one, created inside youre function, is an entirely different object.

In other words, you're printing a property value from the first object, the one pointed to by the **a** in **Main()**.

When you're re-assigning the **a** variable to a *new object* inside your function, the **a** inside **Main()** still points to the original object.

I'm not sure I'm explaining this very well... :) Or perhaps I'm even misunderstanding the question?